# What do I need to do to use smartmenus on bootstrap in a GRAILS-project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

In a Grails-project I want to use NAVBAR(BootStrap) with multilevel dropdown menus and googling around let me know that I should use  smartmenus to make it work.
I found it very hard to find any example that could give me a clue, I think most of them is to old and doesn't work with the latest version of grails and bootstrap.

I've downloaded (cloned a git-repository) smartmenues and found a lot of scripts and stylesheets. But all is just confusing to me.

I would be very happy if I could get some help to put me in the right direction.
//LG

OK, I created a new grails-project(testMultiLevel) and modified the index.gsp as:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Welcome to Grails</title>

    <asset:link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <content tag="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Grails Info <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Application Status <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Environment: ${grails.util.Environment.current.name}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">App profile: ${grailsApplication.config.grails?.profile}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">App version:
                            <g:meta name="info.app.version"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grails version:
                            <g:meta name="info.app.grailsVersion"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Groovy version: ${GroovySystem.getVersion()}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">JVM version: ${System.getProperty('java.version')}</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reloading active: ${grails.util.Environment.reloadingAgentEnabled}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Artefacts <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Controllers: ${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.size()}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Domains: ${grailsApplication.domainClasses.size()}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services: ${grailsApplication.serviceClasses.size()}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tag Libraries: ${grailsApplication.tagLibClasses.size()}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Installed Plugins <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <g:each var="plugin" in="${applicationContext.getBean('pluginManager').allPlugins}">
                            <li><a href="#">${plugin.name} - ${plugin.version}</a></li>
                        </g:each>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </content>

    <div class="svg" role="presentation">
        <div class="grails-logo-container">
            <asset:image src="grails-cupsonly-logo-white.svg" class="grails-logo"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content" role="main">
        <section class="row colset-2-its">
            <h1>Welcome to Grails</h1>

            <p>
                Congratulations, you have successfully started your first Grails application! At the moment
                this is the default page, feel free to modify it to either redirect to a controller or display
                whatever content you may choose. Below is a list of controllers that are currently deployed in
                this application, click on each to execute its default action:
            </p>

            <div id="controllers" role="navigation">
                <h2>Available Controllers:</h2>
                <ul>
                    <g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
                        <li class="controller">
                            <g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link>
                        </li>
                    </g:each>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

This should modify then the top menu to show just one item and then when you clik on it it will show you the 2:nd level. And so far so good but if you click on the 2:nd level you want it to expand but it will not.
I found an example that works but that was not in grails. They used a simple script which I added at the end of the GSP. But it still won't work.

Bootstrap had multilevel menues in earlier versions but they took it away and now it is recommended by using smartmenus. 
The problem is that I can not find anything that tells me how I could integrate smartmenus in the application to make it work.
I need to now what files and where to put these files to make it work.

It's so many combinations so it is not possible to use the TRY-and-Error method.
But maybe there can be other solutions that's simpler then to use smartmenus and that will be ok for me.
//LG

I'm also using a layout here and thats where bootstrap is included. But thats not the end b'cause it's application.js that is included which in turn calls for bootstrap.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>
        <g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/>
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>

    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#">
                    <i class="fa grails-icon">
                        <asset:image src="grails-cupsonly-logo-white.svg"/>
                    </i> Grails
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0.8px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <g:pageProperty name="page.nav" />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <g:layoutBody/>

    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>

    <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
        <g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/>
    </div>

    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you provide your code and exactly where do you find a problem, please?

Comment: are you properly including bootstrap's js?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure even though the NAVBAR works ok except not expanding the lower level. But that's the question what do I need to install and where to be installed and do i need to add some includes into the GSP? etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Grails 3?

From the downloaded zip you probably only need the core *.js and *.css files so put jquery.smartmenus.min.js in \grails-app\assets\javascripts and sm-core-css.css in \grails-app\assets\stylesheets then add the following to \grails-app\assets\stylesheets\application.css

```
//= require sm-core-css
```

And the following to \grails-app\assets\javascripts\application.js

```
//= require jquery.smartmenus.min
```

If you need any of the additional modules you'll just add them to relevant directory and reference in application.*